# angular-auth-oidc-client issue while loading application

Tags: angular, typescript, authorization, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

started getting this issue while loading app, initially it was not happening. any idea?

Thanks in advance

Getting auth well known endpoints failed on start [n]

```
angular-auth-oidc-client.js:169 Getting auth well known endpoints failed on start [n]
logError @ angular-auth-oidc-client.js:169
(anonymous) @ angular-auth-oidc-client.js:1135
error @ catchError.js:27
_error @ tap.js:56
error @ Subscriber.js:55
_error @ Subscriber.js:75
error @ Subscriber.js:55
_error @ Subscriber.js:75
error @ Subscriber.js:55
_error @ Subscriber.js:75
error @ Subscriber.js:55
_tryNext @ mergeMap.js:47
_next @ mergeMap.js:34
next @ Subscriber.js:49
(anonymous) @ subscribeToArray.js:3
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
call @ mergeMap.js:19
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ filter.js:13
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ map.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ map.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ tap.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ catchError.js:14
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ tap.js:16
```

Comment: I have to same problem too.

Comment: @HasanGundogdu - check if you have implemented checkAuth() method at two places / two time. make sure it should not used twice.